# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int' error

Tags: python, list

i have to calculate "a" with this formula:

[image]

The variable "I" is a list, I tried this way but I get this error:

```
a = (675 * 10**-9 * (I**3)) - (771 * 10**-7 * (I**2)) + (1792 * 10**-5 * I) + 0.49239

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: what is I ? could you add it too? here is a run: https://trinket.io/python/2623a17937

Comment: Note that the normal way of writing those numbers in scientific notation would be `675e-9`, `771e-7`, and `1792e-5`, rather than writing out the multiplication and exponentiation in full.

Comment: I is a list formed by 36 values:

Comment: do you need to calculate ```a``` individually for each item in list?

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman yes exactly! I should have a matrix a formed by 36 results.

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese thank you for your help. I'm pretty new in python. How can I upload a matrix in Trinket?

Comment: @Elisam i think that would me a copy and paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using a List Comprehension:

```
I = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = [(675 * 10**-9 * (i**3)) - (771 * 10**-7 * (i**2)) + (1792 * 10**-5 * i + 0.49239) for i in I]
print (a)
```

This prints the following answer:

```
[0.510233575, 0.5279269999999999, 0.545474325, 0.5628795999999999, 0.5801468750000001]
```